# Efficiently pass core data objects to common detailViewController

Tags: core-data, swift4

I have a number of entities that describe different pieces of equipment.

I read these into the EquipmentViewController.

I'm struggling to figure how to use a generic EquipmentDetailViewController that can be used to show and update any of the different entities.

I have it working by having a separate DetailController to manage the details of each entity, but there has to be a better method.

I could possibly merge the entities, but I think that would be unwieldy.

If I could name a variable to hold any entity, I would be set. Is that possible (or correct)?

This must have come up before but I could not find an answer that I understood. If there is one, please point me to it, and I'll close this question.

TIA

Comment: Passing the data should be relatively straightforward- just specify `NSManagedObject` as the type for the relevant property and you can then pass instances of any entity.  But the harder part is identifying the attributes of each entity, their types (string, number, date, boolean, etc) and presenting appropriate UI elements (textfields, date pickers, switches, etc).  It’s all possible, but I’m not sure it will ultimately make life easier.  Is that what you want to do?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I had forgotten that I'd tried setting the type as a managedObject. I ran into the problem you described. Is there an easy way to pull out the UI elements? Otherwise, if you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: You could test the object’s type (or entity), cast accordingly, and then handle each subtype separately, accessing the attributes in code as usual; but if you want a truly generic VC, you can inspect the entity to get the list of attributes (and relationships, if you want)and then build the UI in a tableView, using value(forKey:) and setValue(_, forKey:) to get the attribute values.

Comment: I think I'll write this the long handed way, and give each entity its own viewController. It will make it easier to update elements of the data without having to worry that I'm breaking some other data..